# Problems Configuring Netgear Prosafe 7224v4 Switch

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, dhcp, airport-extreme

Our office has a Netgear Prosafe 7224v2 Switch which was installed a number of years ago.
Currently the switch is not configured to act as a DHCP server thus we need to manually assign all our machines IP's.

This hasn't been a big issue until we recently tried to install an Apple Airport Extreme as our Wireless AP.

The Airport doesn't want to play nice with the Switch unless we manually assign IP's to each mobile device as well. This is painful to say the least.

I've tried to read through the manuals of the 7224v2 and it says that we can use the device as a DHCP server via the Web Interface.

My problem is trying to access the web interface.

When I put the IP of the 7224v2 into my browser as instructed, I get a browser error "Page is not Available". I am able to ping the device.

When I try to Telnet or SSH into the device I also get "Connection Refused" errors.

Heres a link to the Netgear ProSafe 7224v2 manual provided by Netgear http://www.downloads.netgear.com/files/GSM72xxPS/7000_SWA_8.0.2_10Mar10.pdf

Here some info:

The Netgear 7224v2 is on IP 192.168.1.254 (SUBNET 255.255.255.0)
My Macbook Air is is connected to the network using a USB to Ethernet adapter on IP 192.168.1.125

The Airport Extreme is configured currently using Static under the "Internet" tab on IP 192.168.1.250 (SUBNET 255.255.255.0) and Router address 192.168.1.254. Under the "Network" tab the Router Mode is "Off (Bridge Mode)".

If I switch the Router Mode to "DHCP and NAT" then I get Double NAT errors and the data doesn't flow.

Is anyone able to offer some advise as to either/or:
A. How to access the Web Interface of the NetGear 7224v2?
B. Get the Airport Express to play nice with the current config of the Switch?

Comment: Maybe your switch is **not** "Configured for Web Access"? See p1-13 of the manual you reference. Can you configure via the command line interface (using a vt100 terminal) as described on p1-4?

Comment: I imagine that I need to purchase hardware of some form (a cable?) to utilise the vt100 terminal via the serial port on the back?

Answer (score 1):

#### I imagine that I need to purchase hardware of some form (a cable?) to utilise the vt100 terminal via the serial port on the back?

You will need either a **null-modem serial cable** or a **RS-232 crossover cable with a female DB-9 connector** depending on how you are trying to connect.

---

#### Using the EIA-232 Port

> You can use a locally or remotely attached terminal to configure
>   in-band management through the EIA-232 port.
>
> 1. To use a locally attached terminal, attach one end of a **null-modem serial cable** to the EIA-232 port of the switch and the other end to the COM port of the terminal or workstation. For remote
>      attachment, attach one end of the serial cable to the EIA-232 port of
>      the switch and the other end to the modem.
> 2. Set up the terminal for VT100 terminal emulation.
>
>    - a. Set the terminal ON.
>    - b. Launch the VT100 application.
> 3. Configure the COM port as follows:
>
>    - a. Set the data rate to 9600 baud.
>    - b. Set the data format to 8 data bits, 1 stop bit, and no parity.
>    - c. Set the flow control to none.
>    - d. Select the proper mode under Properties.
>    - e. Select Terminal keys.
>
> The Log-in User prompt displays when the terminal interface
>   initializes.
>
> 4. Enter an approved user name and password. The default is admin for the user name and the password is blank.
>
> The switch is installed and loaded with the default configuration.
>
> 7. To enable these changes to be retained during a reset of the switch, type Ctrl-Z to return to the main prompt, type save at the
>      main menu prompt, and type y to confirm the changes.
> 8. To view the changes and verify in-band information, issue the command: show network.
> 9. The switch is configured for in-band connectivity and ready for Web-based management.
>
> **Configuring for Out-Of-Band Connectivity**
>
> To monitor and configure the switch using out-of-band connectivity,
>   use the console port to connect the switch to a terminal desktop
>   system running terminal emulation software. **The console port connector
>   is a male DB-9 connector, implemented as a data terminal equipment
>   (DTE) connector.**
>
> The following hardware is required to use the console port:
>
> - VT100-compatible terminal, or a desktop, or a portable system with a serial port running VT100 terminal emulation software.
> - An **RS-232 crossover cable with a female DB-9 connector** for the console port and the appropriate connector for the terminal.
>
> Perform the following tasks to connect a terminal to the switch
>   console port using out-of-band connectivity:
>
> 1. Connect an **RS-232 crossover cable** to the terminal running VT100 terminal emulation software.
> 2. Configure the terminal emulation software as follows:
>
>    - a. Select the appropriate serial port (serial port 1 or serial port 2) to connect to the console.
>    - b. Set the data rate to 9600 baud.
>    - c. Set the data format to 8 data bits, 1 stop bit, and no parity.
>    - d. Set the flow control to none.
>    - e. Select the proper mode under Properties.
>    - f. Select Terminal keys.
> 3. Connect the female connector of the **RS-232 crossover cable** directly to the switch console port, and tighten the captive retaining
>      screws.

---

#### My problem is trying to access the web interface

You need to configure your switch for web access.

---

#### Configuring for Web Access

> To enable Web access to the switch:
>
> 1. Configure the switch for in-band connectivity (see above)
> 2. Enable Web mode:
>
>    - a. At the CLI prompt, enter the show network command.
>    - b. Set Web Mode to Enabled

---

Source [ProSafe 7000 Managed Switch Software Administration Manual,
Release 8.0.2](http://www.downloads.netgear.com/files/GSM72xxPS/7000_SWA_8.0.2_10Mar10.pdf)

Comment: Thanks David. I have managed to find a Serial to USB cable which the computer store I found it at was grateful to finally unload.

As the interface is only activated when the device is initialised I'll be giving it a go this evening once the team are off the network. Fingers crossed I don't brick it.

Comment: Unfortunately the cable didn't work. Whilst it appeared to be connected, the Terminal wouldn't bring up any login interface. 45 mins on hold waiting for Netgear support yielded only an "escalation".

Comment: Sorry, I'm out of any other ideas :/

Comment: All good. I appreciate your assistance. Will wait for Netgear to make contact and help sort it out. Cheers.